# How to navigate to a page using base_url() function in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I want to navigate to a page after doing some operations. Earlier I navigated like this:

```
echo "<script>alert('not deleted..'); window.location='http://localhost/CodeIgniter/crud/index.php/Crud_C'</script>";
```

And it was working perfectly.

But now I want to navigate like this using base_url():

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo "<script>alert('not deleted..'); window.location='" . <?= base_url('index.php/Crud_C'); ?> . "';</script>";
```

Which is not working. I have used

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/crud/';
```

in config.php file;

What should be the correct syntax of the code after echo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code as below.

```
echo "<script>alert('Not Deleted...'); window.location.href = '" . base_url('index.php/Crud_C') . "'</script>";
```